# ftp hangs in iis 7.5

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5

I've had an IIS 7.5 server running for about a month, but I suddenly noticed that FTP seems to hang. This is best demonstrated in the DOS ftp client.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\jhoge>ftp FTPSite.com
Connected to FTPSite.com.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
User (FTPSite.com:(none)): UserName
331 Password required for UserName.
Password:
230 User logged in.
ftp> dir
[...server hangs here for about a minute ...]
Connection closed by remote host.
```

Answer (score 1):

i've seen that kind of thing before.  hmm.  I would download Wireshark and trace the port 21 traffic to get better info on what is happening.  Personally, I prefer to use [NULL FTP Server](http://www.vwsolutions.com/NullFTPServer/) because I prefer a SFTP (port 22) server over a FTP or FTPS server.